# Unable to access PostgreSQL data

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I inherited a Node.js app that runs on Heroku with PostgreSQL, but as a front-end dev, I'm not very familiar with the database. I'm also not sure if I have full access via the dashboard.

The app feeds off a `source.js` JSON file, which is no longer accessible for some reason. This is the error I see in the app logs (I modified the host domain to post here):

`2021-03-01T19:02:27.609824+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/source.js" host=[app].herokuapp.com request_id=5986f43c-9e0c-477e-be4c-0efaf0d55c10 fwd="72.226.50.247" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https`

When I view the PostgreSQL add-on in Heroku, the health is "Available" with a green checkmark, it says it's on version 9.6.20, and has 1,190 of 10,000 rows in compliance.

What else can I try? Do I need to install PostgreSQL locally to troubleshoot? I just don't understand what changed to lose access. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `source.js` exist in the app tree anywhere? Can you access database directly with another client, say `psql`? I'm guessing this is more a node.js issue then a database/Postgres issue.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That's crossed my mind too. `source.js` doesn't exist in the app codebase and I haven't made any changes to the app in months, so it's not impossible that it's an app issue, but it seems unlikely

Comment: Yet there is: `method=GET path="/source.js"`. So something is looking for it. Until you figure what and why, I'm pretty sure you will not be going anywhere with the app.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I should also mention that the `source.js` file has always been accessible via a direct URL, which no longer works, and that's independent of the app codebase.